# consecutive states in Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory

Let $S = \{1,2\}$ denote a state space and consider a Markov process on $S$ with a positive transition matrix (ie, all entries are strictly positive).  Let $S_\infty = \times_{t=1}^\infty S$ denote the underlying probability space and $\mathbb{P}$ denote the probability measure on $S_\infty$ induced by the Markov transition matrix.

For each $n$, let $F_n := \{ s \in S_\infty : \text{there are at most $n$ consecutive occurrences of $1$ or $2$} \}$.  Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}
\mathbb{P}(F_n) = 1$?

Comment: No, $P(F_n)=0$ for every $n$ except if $p(1,1)=p(2,2)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. Let $A_i$ be the event that $i$ occurs infinitely often. Then $P(A_1\cap A_2)=1$ since $P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1\cup A_2)=2-P(A_1\cup A_2)\geq 1$, since the probability of $1$ or $2$ occuring infinitely often is 1 by ergodicity. It's a fact that any finite irreducible Markov chain with no absorbing states is ergodic in that it visits each state infinitely often with probability 1. Furthermore it will visit each set of positive measure at least once, meaning that it will definitely visit the event that there are more than $n$ consecutive 1's or 2's.

Comment: `consecutive` occurrences.

Comment: Thanks for this.  @Did, I should have said that I want my transition matrix to be strictly positive, so I can rule out your example.  @ Alex R.  How does this show what I had asked?  If I define $F := \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$, then my question was if $\mathbb{P}(F) = 1$.  If I understand your argument correctly, it just says that for each $n$, $\mathbb{P}(F_n) > 0$.  But what about $\mathbb{P}(F)$?